# Log what an application does and accesses

Tags: applications, security, permissions, logging

I'm a bit paranoid about the permissions that certain applications require to work on an Android phone. Specially the "Access to your storage" permission. What I'm scared of is if an application is able to access the internet and is able to access my personal data, it could simply upload it to a unknown destination.

Since I don't know much in Android, I wanted to ask if it would be possible to "log " what an apps is doing on your phone, something like:

- ThisApp entered this folder
- ThisApp used this file
- etc...

Is there any way to do something as I've described above?

Comment: Download a terminal emulator, run *logcat > /sdcard/log.text" ( no quote marks), press enter, then home while nothing is happening. Everything is now being logged to a text file on your internal storage

Comment: i guess i have to be root to do this ?

Comment: No, actually. It's a fairly low-level job. But with root, it will show more